# How to save the ID of the selected hobbies in database in yii 1.13

Tags: php, mysql, yii

[image: My Registration Page]I need to store the id of the selected hobbies from my check box in database. First, in my Hobbies table, i view all the hobby names and display it in check box. Now, whichever the hobbies selected, it stores the id of the hobbies in another table.

This is my code in **views/sample/register.php**

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'hobby');
    $opts = CHtml::listData(Hobbies::model()->findAll(),'hobby_id','hobby_name');
    echo $form->checkBoxList($model,'hobby',$opts, array('labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:inline'),'separator'=>'  '));
    echo $form->error($model,'hobby'); ?>
</div>
```

And this is my code in **controllers/SampleController.php**

```
if($model->validate())
        {
            $model->hobby = implode(",",$model->hobby);
            if($model->save())
            {
               $this->redirect(array('site/login'));
            }
            return;
        }
```

But it displays an error as ***PHP warning mb_strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given***. Please anybody help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your controller

```
$postArr = $_POST[<FORM NAME>]; //Post data to an array
$model->hobby = implode(", ", $postArr['hobby']); //Getting details from post array
if($model->validate())
    {
        if($model->save())
        {
           $this->redirect(array('site/login'));
        }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Same error @srininvasa Reddy. And if i doesn't gave any code in my controller also, it shows the same error. I think i had problem in my view file. But i don't know how to rectify it.

Comment: First check $opts returns an array or not. And if it returns array then try this code in next line                                                                                         echo $form->checkBoxList($model,'hobby',$opts);

Comment: I had added a screenshot. This is my registration page. See there, it displays the hobby names from the database.

Comment: Check the state field. If it is empty dropdownlist, you have to pass an empty array.

Comment: See this link. [link](http://i63.tinypic.com/kc1pts.png). Here i removed state field. But it displays same error.

Comment: Check your validation rule for checkboxlist. First test with out validation for hobby attribute(the checkboxlist). If working fine then write the validation in attached link format http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/10463-checkboxlist-rule/